# How can I de-fisheye NASA InSight raw images?

Tags: nasa, photography, insight

NASA Insight (as other past and future missions) provide distorted images.
Which site can I use to automatically fix such distortion, without downloading and processing each single image I am interested on?

This site looks promising but I can't get suitable prameters for Insight images: https://jywarren.github.io/fisheyegl/example/#a=0.853&b=1.243&Fx=0.29&Fy=0.18&scale=1.029&x=0.908&y=0.915

It would be also interesting to be able to reproject such images in equirectangular projection, as such projection can be seen on VR viewers and panorama viewers and even directly uploaded to facebook for immediate sharing and to use the phone gyro+accel to view around them.

Insight nasa images: https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/multimedia/raw-images/?order=sol+desc%2Cdate_taken+desc&per_page=50&page=0&mission=insight

Comment: Although I can't speak for @GdD and the other close voters, I would assume that editing the question to something like "What are the lens distortion parameters of the InSight cameras?" would probably make it on-topic here.

Comment: I agree with @IlmariKaronen and I've added the `photography` tag who's definition is *Questions on taking images in space or of spacecraft.* As the question is about images of a spacecraft, I think it's on-topic enough to keep open.

Comment: @GdD a helpful edit is less punative and more productive than the insta-close. With the new edit and the `photography` tag and its definition, can we classify this as "about space exploration" and therefore as a keeper?

Comment: information on the InSight cameras: https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2018/pdf/2764.pdf

Comment: The question said "how do I edit distortion in photos" @uhoh, the edited version is very far from the original and I am not sure it is actually the original intent.

Comment: @GdD still sounds punitive to me, or perhaps like SE is a game of [Asteroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game)) or "so what you did wrong is..." *pew! pew!* Here's someone who would like to adjust images of and from a spacecraft on Mars, and they asked in the right place. Why not work together to help them get what they need and at the same time show them a better way to do it? It doesn't have to be either/or.

Comment: @uhoh, your comments are not constructive. I didn't see any space content or a way to salvage the question so I voted to close, that's all. If jumpjack is happy with the edits and people have answers then that's cool by me.

Comment: @BoostedNub the note explains why the urls are shown explicitly. You made **Note:** bold, then defeated the purpose of the note by hiding them. I've rolled back. It's not uncommon for SE users to show full urls from time to time if there is some information there you'd like people to see even if they don't hover.

Comment: the question was not "which is the FOV?", an info which can easily be found in NASA docs. The question was: how to fix the distortion in these Martian images?
The answer will be applicabile to any future space mission.
A link to an algorithm is not the right answer.

Comment: If you feel the question as edited no longer represents your intent you should edit it so that it does.

Comment: You may search for software correcting  barrel distortion as explained in the question [What is the difference between perspective distortion and barrel or pincushion distortion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85526/what-is-the-difference-between-perspective-distortion-and-barrel-or-pincushion-d). I suggest [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Lens_correction_model.html)